# How somebody can get rid of Vyanthara?

Tags: scripture, mantras, astrology, life

I want to know what is Vyanthara and how to get rid from them.

Comment: What is Vyanthara?

Comment: A type of spirit which invade body

Comment: Do you mean the [type of nagas](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083524.html)?